# ActiveMQ ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue getting bigger and bigger

Tags: activemq-classic, jms-topic

Problem, 
on ActiveMQ for some reasons(I dont know why) the ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue is getting bigger and bigger (1GB per day).
here is a snapshot:

```
 Name                      Producer #   Consumer #  Enqueue #   Dequeue #   Memory %    Dispatch #  Always retroactive  Average blocked time    Average enqueue time    Average message size    Blocked producer warning interval   Blocked sends   Dlq Expired count   Forward count   In flight count Max audit depth Max enqueue time    Max message size    Max page size   Max producers to audit  Memory limit    Memory usage byte count Memory usage portion    Min enqueue time    Min message size    Options Prioritized messages    Producer flow control   Queue size  Slow consumer strategy  Store message size  Total blocked time  Use cache   Object name

ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue |   0 | 816 | 187550135 |   0 | 0 | 187836323 | FALSE | 0 | 0.3694736   | 1024 |    30000 | 0    | FALSE |  0 | 0 | 187836323 | 2048 |  1233 |  1024 |  200 |   1024 |  668309914 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1024 |      FALSE | TRUE |  0 |     0 | 0 | TRUE |  org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Topic,destinationName=ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue
```

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Advisory Topics in ActiveMQ don't accumulate data, they are Topics and as such when there are no consumers on the Topics the messages sent to them are dropped.  If you have a consumer on the advisory Topic then message pass through it but are not stored in the persistent storage on the broker.  The stats can sometimes be deceiving given the enqueue count keeps ticking up.

Without knowing more about what you are seeing there's not much more help that can be offered.

If you are seeing growth in the KahaDB logs then it is unrelated to your Advisory Topics as I've stated they don't store messages ever so there is something else going on.  There's some nice [instructions](http://activemq.apache.org/why-do-kahadb-log-files-remain-after-cleanup.html) on the ActiveMQ WebSite on how to take a look at what is keeping the KahaDB journal files alive which you should use to help debug your issue.

Comment: what data do you need to figure it out? My problem is that the ActiveMQ space occupied by log files is increased approximately with 1GB per day. I dot know if it is safe to delete them. I looked in the console and i seen the  ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue continuously increasing... 180 million messages... I thought that this ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue is creating the problems.

Comment: Which log files, KahaDB?  We can't know what's on your system until you tell us.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the web console where i can see that administrative topic. And yes the it is using KahaDB.

Comment: That doesn't really help at all but I've added a link to instructions on debugging KahaDB log retention you should use.

Comment: Thank you, Ill check if that helps me.